# Printing UI Controls

Tags: .net, wpf, layout, printing, flowdocument

I'm trying to print the contents of a canvas with some other UI elements but having very limited success. Is there any way to construct the elements to a Grid for example instead, then print the contents rendered at a desired page size?

This was, I could get the benefit of databinding and vastly easier layout without using System.Windows.Documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this good short article called [Printing WPF window(visual) to printer and fit on a page](http://a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?id=66#.Uf-rl5xwZnc). It shows the basics of printing in WPF, but also how to size the visual to fit the page.